# How to get the state of a transition animation

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to tell, **at a certain point in time**, if the [`Navigator`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html) is in the middle of a transition?

The context to the question is that I want to be sure that no transition animation is currently ongoing on screen (back or forward).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot know that from the navigator instance. Navigator is not aware of transitions. It's the job of [Route](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Route-class.html), not Navigator.

To solve your needs you'll need two things:

- Obtain all the routes. This can be done with a NavigatorObserver.
- Make sure that the routes your app use correctly expose the state of their animations.
  Not all routes expose it. But usually, you're using [ModalRoute](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ModalRoute-class.html), which indeed do.

Here's a full NavigatorObserver that obtains all the routes, and expose a getter to know if there's currently an animation or not:

```dart
class AllRoutes extends ValueNotifier<List<Route>> with NavigatorObserver {
  AllRoutes() : super(const []);

  bool _isAnimating(Animation a) =>
      a.status == AnimationStatus.forward ||
      a.status == AnimationStatus.reverse;

  NavigationTransitionStatus get animationStatus {
    for (final route in value) {
      if (route is ModalRoute &&
          (_isAnimating(route.animation) ||
              _isAnimating(route.secondaryAnimation))) {
        return NavigationTransitionStatus.animating;
      }
    }
    return NavigationTransitionStatus.idle;
  }

  @override
  void didPush(Route route, Route previousRoute) {
    value = [...value, route];
  }

  @override
  void didReplace({Route newRoute, Route oldRoute}) {
    value = [...value]..[value.indexOf(oldRoute)] = newRoute;
  }

  @override
  void didPop(Route route, Route previousRoute) {
    value = [...value]..remove(route);
  }

  @override
  void didRemove(Route route, Route previousRoute) {
    value = [...value]..remove(route);
  }
}
```

You have to first pass it to your "MaterialApp" equivalent:

```dart
final myObserver = AllRoutes();

MaterialApp(
  navigatorObservers: [myObserver],
)
```

You can then do:

```dart
myObserver.animationStatus == NavigationTransitionStatus.animating;
```

Comment: I think that `didPop` is called immediately before the animation had time to finish, so the list of routes will not have the animating "popped" Route when we check for the animation status. I guess that could be mitigated by removing the Route from the list only after animations finished. Thanks for the help.